# EasyNetQ TaskCanceledException for Request/Response

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, easynetq

I'm trying to implement a simple .NET 6 microservice with RabbitMQ using EasyNetQ.

I have 2 completely different projects in 2 completely different solutions and when I try to use [EasyNetQ's Request/Response](https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Request-Response) I am able to send the request, my responder receives it and I'm able to process it, however the original caller never gets a response back. I get a `TaskCanceledException` in my `RequestService.cs` saying: "A task was canceled."

`RequestService.cs`

```
var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost;timeout=120;username=guest;password=guest");

var req = new SendMessageRequestModel
{
    SenderUsername = "me",
    ReceiverUsername = "alsoMe",
    DateSent = DateTime.Now,
    Content = "message"
};

//This following line works and sends the request successfully.
var response = await bus.Rpc.RequestAsync<SendMessageRequestModel, Result<bool>>(req);

// However it does not receive a response and here is where I get the TaskCanceledException.

Console.WriteLine("Response is:" + response.IsSuccessful);
Console.ReadLine();
bus.Dispose();
```

Here is the `ReceiverService.cs`

```
var bus = RabbitHutch.CreateBus("host=localhost;timeout=120;username=guest;password=guest");

await bus.Rpc.RespondAsync<SendMessageRequestModel, Result<bool>>(req =>
{
   Console.WriteLine("Request made at: " + DateTime.UtcNow);
   // Breakpoint here works.

   return Result<bool>.Success(true);
});

Console.ReadLine();
bus.Dispose();
```

Here is the exception:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at EasyNetQ.DefaultRpc.RequestAsync[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, Action`1 configure, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\Other\TempMQReceiver\temp\TempSender\TempSender\Program.cs:line 14
   at Program.<Main>(String[] args)
```

Answer (score 2):

I eventually found the problem. It turns out my `Result<bool>` did not have a parameterless constructor and `Newtonsoft.Json` threw an exception. I was able to locate the error by going to the default error queue (`EasyNetQ_Default_Error_Queue`) which EasyNetQ creates.